# JQUERY: How do you pass a function as a parameter to $()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

How do you pass a function as a parameter to $()?
For example

```
function autoplace(map){
  // do something with map
   };
var map = "Wassup";
$(autoplace(map));  // how to pass a function which takes a parameter, as a paramter to $()
```

Comment: You should specify the technologies in the tags and/or question.  Javascript and jquery?

Comment: yes which language / framework!

Comment: Hi Robert/tgkprog, this is Jquery. Please help.

Comment: What is your purpose of 
"pass a function which takes a parameter, as a paramter to $() "

Answer (score 0):

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

`$()` takes in different types of parameters in different situations.

So the point should be what your `autoplace()` function is **returning**. Then what returns gets passed into `$()`

Example:

```
function autoplace(map) {

     var mapSelector = '#map_' + map,
         $map = $(mapSelector);

     // do something with map

     // return something that's suitable for $()
     // Just an example

     return mapSelector; // In this example, mapSelector ends up being '#map_Wassup'
}

var $myMap = $( autoplace('Wassup') );

// The result will be equivalent to $('#map_Wassup')
```

Comment: Glad that was what you asked for. Please consider marking this as the answer if you see fit.